# C++ Header #define compiler error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, header-files, build-error

I'm learning C++ and I'm at a fairly low level still. - I'm currently looking at using header files and I have a two part question.

**Part 1**

As I understand them so far, header file definitions are similar to hard coded strings within VB.net? For example I can do the following `#define STOCK_QUANTITY 300` and then reference my definition when using it within functions? I assume this works the same way as VB.net strings as I only need to change the value in one place should I need to make changes to the definition and my program references the number 300 on a few hundred different lines?

**Part 2**

Now, as I said I'm still learning so I'm still doing ye old multiplication tasks. I'm good within using functions with my main .cpp file but I'm not moving on to header files. This is my code snippet thus far.

**add.h**

```
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H

int add(int x, int y);

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "add.h"

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << add(3, 4) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When trying to run this I receive 2 build errors and it will not compile.
[image]

Apologies is these are silly questions, but I would appreciate insight, tips or even some other things I should consider. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Based on an answer I've changed my add.h too

```
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H

int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

#endif
```

As soon as I read the answer I realised I hadn't even told the function what to do :( - Gosh.

Comment: ObSocraticMethod: What do you expect that your program will do?  Return the result of adding the numbers?  How would it know to do that?  Just because you called the function add?

Comment: See my edit, I realised my mistake of not actually defining the function. *sighs*

Comment: I actually don't know what exactly are VB.NET hardcoded strings, but in C++ the best way to understand macros (ie `#define`d values) is that they are juste tokens that are replaced with their value (like an automatic copy-paste system).

Comment: Yeh that's how I understand them, exactly how it was in VB.net accept you defined them within the project settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not added a function body for the function add

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    // add stuff here
}
```

This can be done in either the header file, or a seperate cpp file for add. You are trying to call the function that has no code. This is known as a function prototype.

Comment: I guess I need to add return x + y; then within the function body or whatever I want it to print within the console?

Comment: @SamuelNicholson Indeed :)

Answer (score 2):

You have only declared that the function `add` exists, which is why you can call it. But you don't actually *define* the function anywhere.

In C++ you have to differ between *declaration* and *definition*. Sometimes those are done at the same time, like when declaring a local variable. Other times you separate them, like when having a function prototype in a header file (like you do) then that's the declaration. The definition of the function is then the implementation of the function.

---

After the edit, you now have another problem. And that is if you include the header file in multiple source files, each of those source files (formally known as translation units) will have the function defined and you will get an error because of that.

It *can* be solved by making the function `static` or `inline`. Or better yet, create a new source file (like `add.cpp`) where you have the definition of the `add` function, and keep only the declaration (prototype) in the header file.

Comment: See my edit, I just added that after I realised the silly mistake I made :0

Comment: @SamuelNicholson That edit may lead to other problems. Updated my answer to include them.

Comment: It can also be solved by adding a .cpp file and putting the function in there

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I haven't actually made it that far in my learning, I'm just trying to learn how  to use multiple files at the moment and interlinking everything but I understand the point you raise but not yet how to address it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As for part 1 of your question:
While #defines do as you described, there are some of disadvantages with using them (e.g. They are parsed by the pre-processor, and not by the compiler so no type checking, and also you can get funky errors if you have slightly more complicated macros.
So while your statement is valid, in that it defines a global constant that you only need to modify in one place, and can use in multiple places, for that purpose it is better to have an actual constant variable in the header file:
e.g.

```
const int STOCK_QUANTITY = 300;
```

Now you explicitly name it an integer, and also the compiler can perform extra checking.

See also Item 3 in Effective C++ by Scott Meyer (which is a must read in my opinion if you are serious about contineouing programming in c++, although you need allready some experience before reading that.)